# Hover effects all div above and under social icons

Tags: html, css, hover

When I hover over a social-media icon, the whole column gets effected with the hover.

I have 3 divs above this code and one under. they all get effected.

```css
.social-media-Urban {background-color:yellow;}
.social-media-Urban ul li a {
    display: block;
    width: 61px;
    height: 66px;
}
.social-media-Urban ul li:hover {
    top: -3px;
    opacity: 0.7;

.facebook_urban {
    background: url('i.imgur.com/rjoSuNv.png');
    background-position: top -2px left 134px;
}
.twitter_urban {
    background: url('i.imgur.com/rjoSuNv.png');
    background-position: top -2px left -8px;
}
.instagram_urban {
    background: url('http://i.imgur.com/rjoSuNv.png');
    background-position: top -2px left 67px;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-media-Urban">
 <ul>
  <li class="facebook_urban"><a href="https://www.facebook.com/"></a></li>
  <li class="twitter_urban"><a href="https://twitter.com/"></a></li>
  <li class="instagram_urban"><a href="https://www.instagram.com/"></a></li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: So what is your exact question? What is the problem in this scenario?

Comment: all the column gets effected 
<div>Logo</div>
<div>Some text</div>
<a>links</a>
<div> HOVER EFFECTS AND SOCIAL ICONS</DIV>
<div>COPY RIGHT</div>

Comment: I have no clue what you are trying to accomplish. What is the problem and what is the result you want? Your question is very unclear!

Comment: your css bracket  is not closed:`.social-media-Urban ul li:hover {
    top: -3px;
    opacity: 0.7;`.

Answer (score 0):

For example
all the column gets effected

```html
<div>Logo</div>
<div>Some text</div>
<a>links</a>
<div> HOVER EFFECTS AND SOCIAL ICONS</DIV>
<div>COPY RIGHT</div>
```

All the divs got effected

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what's the problem here, but I've cleaned your code for you -- you were missing some syntax:

**EDIT #1:** The reason the hover effect is affecting all your list is because you forgot to close the styling for `.social-media-Urban ul li:hover`.

```css
.social-media-Urban {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.social-media-Urban ul li a {
  display: block;
  width: 61px;
  height: 66px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.social-media-Urban ul li a:hover {
  top: -3px;
  opacity: 0.7;
}

.facebook_urban a {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/rjoSuNv.png');
  background-position: top -2px left 134px;
}

.twitter_urban a {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/rjoSuNv.png');
  background-position: top -2px left -8px;
}

.instagram_urban a {
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/rjoSuNv.png');
  background-position: top -2px left 67px;
}
```

```html
<div class="social-media-Urban">
  <ul>
    <li class="facebook_urban">
      <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="twitter_urban">
      <a href="https://twitter.com/"></a>
    </li>
    <li class="instagram_urban">
      <a href="https://www.instagram.com/"></a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: oh its closed I just forgot that during the copy paste

Comment: I've updated the code; that's probably how you'd want it to look?

Answer (score 0):

You want the hover to affect only the URL being hovered, not the list. Try:

```
.social-media-Urban ul li a:hover {
   top: -3px;
   opacity: 0.7;
}
```